# Setup a Windows Azure Private Cloud

Tags: azure

I want to use Windows Azure. However, my admin guy is fighting against me using it. From my understanding, I can setup a private cloud so that I can use Azure's features, but on an internal environment. I have convinced him to let me try it. I have one Windows Server 2008 server that I can try this out on. Unfortunately, I don't know how to setup a private cloud.

Does anyone know of a step-by-step walkthrough of how to do this? Or am I misunderstanding the idea of a private cloud? Thank you so much for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set up a private cloud using Windows Azure.

If you want to set this up internally on Server 2008 you should look at System Center or Hyper V for hosting VMs. It will be quite a large underatking to do this reliably, and if you are new to the technology there will be a lot to learn.

If you would like to use Windows Azure you can currently hosy Virtual Machines in the Windows Azure data centers. This is very easy to get started with, will be much more productive than creating an on-preimise solution.

You can register for a free 90 day Azure trial account here: 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/

There is some information on Windows Azure Virtual Machines here: 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/virtual-machines/

There are some VM labs in the Windows Azure Training kit here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396

It will probably take you about 15 minutes to get your first Windows Server 2008 Virtual Machine up and running in Azure.

Regards,

Alan

Comment: Is that still true now ? I heard about Windows Azure Pack, which I guess can be used to create private windows azure! 
Am I right ?

Answer (score 3):

As @Alan pointed out, you can not create a Windows Azure private cloud. However: If you're a hosting service provider, you can now start working with two Windows Azure services on Windows Server+System Center: Websites and Virtual Machine provisioning, along with service management API and portal. More details are [here](http://www.microsoft.com/hosting/en/us/services.aspx).

Also: You can create a hybrid environment: Windows Azure services in the cloud, and local services in your own data center, bridged via  Virtual Network VPN. Here's [some info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156007.aspx) on Virtual Networks from MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

If you own the data center, you can setup a private cloud with the help of windows azure pack.

WAP is simply a control panel of managing your cloud. It offered an option to create and manage VM"S on your data center.

Vconnect with vm ware and billing integrations on azure pack details are available on the following link. Register here for free demo trial access
http://www.cloudassert.com/Solutions/VConnect

From my personal experience, I am suggesting [Cloud Assert](http://www.cloudassert.com), a team made of founders who are ex-Microsoft managers with many years of hands-on experience in designing, building and running truly large scale hosted services on Windows Azure.

They helped me in setting up my own private cloud and educated through customized solution that works best for my use cases.

Also, Cloud Assert will help to create hybrid cloud environment as well. [For more details](http://www.cloudassert.com)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure is for public cloud. For private cloud, Microsoft's solution is Azure Stack (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/azure-stack/). Take care checking the hardware requirements before taking actions.